# How to trigger a "pull to refresh" style refresh in one/one.app

Tags: salesforce1-app, aura

I'm trying to find the proper JS call, or calls needed to refresh the data of a feed view in one/one.app

I can force a reload of the entire app, but that's costly and ugly. I'd much rather just trigger a refresh as if I'd pulled down to refresh.

Anyone know the right mix of js and aura ?